# asprintf(): how to free the pointers?

Tags: c, linux

I have code like this: I assigned log twice, is there potential memory leak for the first &log?

```
char *log = NULL;
asprintf(&log, "Hello: %s", name);
if (known_person== true){
    asprintf(&log, "%s, %s", log, ", my old friend.");
}
free (log);
```

Comment: yes, you're leaking memory. the string that the first asprintf created and saved a pointer to in log is now deleted/gone

Comment: @MarcB: "*the string that the first `asprintf `created [...] now deleted/gone*" This is not correct, as the "string", that is the memory which has been allocated, still *is* allocated. However the reference to it (as 1st stored in `log`) is gone. So the memory cannot be `free()`ed any more, which commonly is called a "memory leak".

Comment: @alkk: yeah, bad phrasing on my part. the POINTER is dead/gone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the code will leak, since `asprintf` neither checks, nor attempts to reuse, the previous pointer. Hence, the memory is simply lost. The best way to avoid the problem in your example would be to rewrite the code as

```
char *log = NULL;
if (known_person== true)
    asprintf(&log, "Hello: %s, my old friend.", name);
else
    asprintf(&log, "Hello: %s", name);

free (log);
```

That way, the buffer is allocated once and freed correctly.

Alternatively, you could use two pointers

```
char *temp = NULL;
asprintf(&temp, "Hello: %s", name);

char *log = NULL;
if (known_person== true) {
    asprintf(&log, "%s, my old friend.", temp);
    free( temp );
}
else {
    log = temp;
}

free (log);
```

Comment: The 1st approach fully ignores the DRY principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Comment: How important is it to check that the return value of `asprintf()` is not -1 before `free(log)`?

Comment: @alk True, which is why I provided the alternative. Ironically, the alternative non-repetitive code is longer, more error prone, and harder to maintain correctly.

Comment: @chux It's not important to check for -1, as `asprintf` will set the pointer to `NULL` on failure. Checking the pointer before using it would be necessary, but using the pointer was not part of OP's question. Calling `free` with a `NULL` pointer is allowed by the C specification, so that's not an issue.

Comment: Hmmm , with `int asprintf(char **strp, ...` I thought "If memory allocation wasn't possible, or some other error occurs, these functions will return -1, and the contents of strp is undefined."

Comment: @chux: Good catch. My conclusion ever was to *not* use `aprintf()` at all, and that "just" because of this "*...or some other error occurs ... the contents of strp is undefined.*". Much to vague how to handle `strp` on error.

Comment: @chux Hmmm, `asprintf` doesn't appear in the C spec. On OS X, which is what I'm using, the man page says *"If sufficient space cannot be allocated, asprintf() and vasprintf() will return -1 and set `ret` to be a NULL pointer."* So I guess that's why one should not to use non-standard functions in portable code.

Comment: @chux The work-around would be `if (asprintf(&ptr,...)<0) ptr=NULL;`. That would give consistent behavior on both platforms.

Comment: @user3386109: There is no guarantee that *no* memory had been allocate to `*strp`  in case of "*some other error*".

Comment: @alk Perhaps, except that you can't do anything about that case, given that *"the contents of strp is undefined"*. So you have to assume that `asprintf` cleans up its own mess before returning -1. Or, as you already said, just don't use `asprintf`.

Answer (score 2):

> is there [a] [...] memory leak

Definitely yes.

The reference to the memory allocated by the 1st call to `aprintf()` gets overwritten by the 2nd call to `aprintf()`, so there is no chance to `free()` the 1st allocated memory any more, it "leaks".

To fix this introduce a 2nd (temporary) pointer:

```
char name[] = "C";
char * log = NULL;

{
  char * log_tmp = NULL;

  asprintf(&log_tmp, "Hello: %s", name);
  if (known_person == true)
  {
    asprintf(&log, "%s, %s", log_tmp, ", my old friend.");
    free(log_tmp);
  }
  else
  {
    log = log_tmp;
  }
}

/* Use log. */

free(log);
```

A different and probably cheaper (faster as some stuff is handle during compilation time, but run-time) approach to this issue would be the following:

```
#define FORMAT_STR "Hello: %s"
#define FORMAT_SUFFIX_STR ", my old friend."

...

char name[] = "C";
char * log = NULL;

{
  char format[sizeof FORMAT_STR""FORMAT_SUFFIX_STR + 1] = FORMAT_STR;

  if (known_person == true)
  {
    strcat(format, FORMAT_SUFFIX_STR);
  }

  asprintf(&log, format, name);
}

/* Use log. */

free(log);
```

Adding error checking on system calls is left to reader as an exercise.

A 3rd approach to this only using Standard C functions is:

```
char name[] = "C";
char * log = NULL;

{
  char * log_tmp = NULL;

  asprintf(&log_tmp, "Hello: %s", name);
  if (known_person == true)
  {
    asprintf(&log, "%s, %s", log_tmp, ", my old friend.");
    free(log_tmp);
  }
  else
  {
    log = log_tmp;
  }
}

/* Use log. */

free(log);
```

A different and probably cheaper (faster as some stuff is handle during compilation time, but run-time) approach to this issue would be the following:

```
#define FORMAT_STR "Hello: %s"
#define FORMAT_SUFFIX_STR ", my old friend."

...

char name[] = "C";
char * log = NULL;

{
  char format[sizeof FORMAT_STR""FORMAT_SUFFIX_STR + 1] = FORMAT_STR;

  if (known_person == true)
  {
    strcat(format, FORMAT_SUFFIX_STR);
  }

  {
    int s = snprintf(NULL, 0, format, name);
    if (-1 == s) 
    {
      /* failure */
    }
    else
    {
      log = malloc(s + 1);
      if (NULL == log)
      {
        /* failure */
      }
      else
      {
        if (-1 == sprintf(log, format, name))
        {
          /* failure */
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

free(log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Likely `asprinf` won't hit the same memory place and has no knowledge of the previous calls.